# Find something between parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I got a string like that:

```
LD(_030S.F.IN)OR(_080T_SAF_OUT)COIL(xxSF[4].Flt[120].0)
```

I want to look only for `OR(_080T_SAF_OUT)COIL(xxSF[4].Flt[120].0)`, but the `OR` could be `LD` as well. `_080T_SAF_OUT` could be different being always alphanumeric with bottom slash sometimes. `COIL(xxSF[4].Flt[120].0)`, must be always in the format `COIL(xxSF["digits"].Flt["digits"]."digits")`

I am trying to use the re library of Python 2.7.

```
m = re.search('\OR|\LD'+'\('+'.+'+'\)'+'+'\COIL+'\('+'\xxSF+'\['+'\d+'+'\].'+ Flt\['+'\d+'+'\]'+'\.'+'\d+', Text)
```

My Output:

```
OR(abc_TEST_X)LD(xxSF[16].Flt[0].22
OR
LD(TEST_X_dsfa)OR(WASS_READY)COIL(xxSF[16].Flt[11].10
```

The first one is the right one which I am getting I want to discard the second one and the third one.

I think that the problem is here:

```
'\('+'.+'+'\)'
```

Because of I just want to find something alphanumeric and possibly with symbols between the first pair of paréntesis, and I am not filtering this situation.

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces (preferable), but for inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with backticks (`\``).

Comment: Group alternations. `(?:LD|OR)`, and to match any chars other than `(` and `)` you may use `[^()]*` rather than `.+`

Answer (score 1):

You should group alternations like `(?:LD|OR)`, and to match any chars other than `(` and `)` you may use `[^()]*` rather than `.+` (`.+` matches any chars, as many as possible, hence it matches across parentheses).

Here is a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sgrJRM):

```
import re
Text = 'LD(_030S.F.IN)OR(_080T_SAF_OUT)COIL(xxSF[4].Flt[120].0)'
m = re.search(r'(?:OR|LD)\([^()]*\)COIL\(xxSF\[\d+]\.Flt\[\d+]\.\d+', Text)
if m:
    print(m.group()) # => OR(_080T_SAF_OUT)COIL(xxSF[4].Flt[120].0
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?:OR|LD)` - a non-capturing group matching `OR` or `LD`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - a negated character class matching 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)COIL\(xxSF\[` - `)COIL(xxSF[` substring
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `]\.Flt\[` - `].Flt[` substring
- `\d+]\.\d+` - 1+ digits, `].` substring and 1+ digits

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RTydT2/1).

**TIP** Add a `\b` before `(?:OR|LD)` to match them as whole words (not as part of `NOR` and `NLD`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I am capturing everything which I want. Just something else to filter. Take a look to some Outputs:

OR(_1B21_A53021_2_En)OR(_1_A21_Z53021_2)COIL(xxSF[9].Flt[15].3);

LD(_1B21_A53021_2_En)LD(_1_A21_Z53021_2)COIL(xxSF[9].Flt[15].3);

I only want to capture the last one "LD" or "OR" as follow:

OR(_1_A21_Z53021_2)COIL(xxSF[9].Flt[15].3);

LD(_1_A21_Z53021_2)COIL(xxSF[9].Flt[15].3);